# Debugging an IOS App on a Device

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

1. Is there any up-to-date, step-by-step instructions for running an IOS APP on a device?
2. For example, in these instructions, I have made it through step 3.

   http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-test-your-app-on-an-ios-device--mobile-13861

At step for, it says to click "Use For Development"

When I have my device connected, there is no "Use for Development" button on that screen.

Comment: It might say Add to Member Center

Comment: Have you ever clicked Use For Development on your device in the past?

Comment: I did that before posting. A click ADD, it gives my a list of accounts (one entry with mine). I select it. I get the barber pole for a bit, then it is back they way it was.

Comment: Which version of iOS is your device running and what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Device is 7.1. XCode 5.1.

Comment: The official documentation is quite useful in this regard: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RunYourApp/RunYourApp.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the same but with less detail. Still does not say what to do when no response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for "Use for Development".

1. connect your device.
2. Open X-Code.
3. select Window menu and choose Organizer.
   4.Select Devices.
4. Your device would be listed on the left tab.
5. Select the device.
6. Use should find the use for development button in the details pane (right pane) along with other details about device.

If everything is good ,you would have a green light indicator. Else there would be a red/yellow indicator besides your device name in left pane. When you select the device, the issue would be displayed in the right pane.

Comment: Somehow I got it working. I have no idea what I did but eventually, it worked. I wish I could share an answer but I have none.